# Как из ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'] сделать 'hello'?

Tags: python-3.x

Я знаю как из `hello` сделать `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`.

```
list('hello')
```

А как сделать наоборот?

Comment: `''.join(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'])`

Comment: *>>Я знаю как...* - важно не только знать, но понимать, почему это так работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_List = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3']
my_String = ''.join(myList) # '' - разделитель между элементами списка соответственно
```